# error when having class method in a generic class with same name as non-generic super class

Tags: ios, generics, swift

The following code causes an error `Ambiguous use of 'B'`:

```
public class A {
    public class func B<T>(t: T) -> T {
        return t
    }

}
public class AT<T> : A {
    public class func B<T1>(t: T1) -> T1 {
        return t
    }
}
println(AT<Int>.B("a"))
```

But when trying to add `override` to method `B` in `AT<T>`, got the error `Method does not override any method from its superclass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override the function since the parameter types are difference, hence, one function cannot act as the other. Also, you cannot use the same method signature, if it already exists. The only solution is to change the name, or use the same type for the parameter as the superclass. Also, you cannot hide methods in superclasses, but you could throw an exception if it is used by overriding it.